# find package rbx1 wrote by c++

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I read the book ros_by_example_hydro_volune_1 I find the program are all wrote by python. Have someone find the same program wrote by c++.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200015/find-package-rbx1-wrote-by-c++/) by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think there are versions of these packages in C++. You may want to go through the ROS C++ tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0